# Switch case is not working

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char option='0';
    do
    {

        cin >> option;
        switch (option) 
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "testing 1\n";
                break;
            case '2':
                cout << "testing 2\n";
                break;
            case '3':
                cout << "Thank you, Have a nice day.\n";
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid option, Please enter option (1-3).";
        }

    }while (option != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why the while loop is infinite. When i key in `3`, it should print out `Thank you, Have a nice day.` and exit the loop `while (option != 3)`. However, it seems that the while loop is not working.

Comment: `3` is not `'3'`; you want `while (option != '3');`.

Comment: You can convert from int to char using (3 + '0')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
while (option != 3);
```

to

```
while (option != '3');
```

3 is not same as '3'. One is integer and other is character.

Comment: Offtopic: you were a bit too quick to delete that question of yours. But well: deleting was the correct decision. Seriously: it doesn't happen too often that people accept it when they get such feedback. Thus I am showing my appreciation here. Then: a) you could try asking on quora.com instead b) the main problem with your question: it was too unspecified. And cross tagging is also not a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is declared as a char, and the wile loop is comparing the value as an integer.

You should change the signature of your variable to a numeric one (integer, long, short, etc), or change the while loop condition to evaluate to a character value (option != '3'), or you can even compare the option variable to the equivalent numeric value ('0' = 48, '1' = 49...).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that in while loop you check for whether option != 3 which is comparing char and int. What you should do instead is option != '3', like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char option;
    do {

        cin >> option;
        switch (option) {
        case '1':
            cout << "testing 1\n";
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "testing 2\n";
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "Thank you, Have a nice day.\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option, Please enter option (1-3).";
        }
    } while (option != '3');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (option != 3); //Here is your problem.
```

3 vs '3' are different.
you should write `while (option != '3');`